# How to check Knox Warranty status for Samsung Tab S6 (T865)?

Tags: samsung-knox, samsung-galaxy-tab-s-6

How to check Knox Warranty status for Samsung Tab S6 (T865) if it is tripped or not?

I go to recovery screen by Power + Volume Up and from there selecting "Reboot to Bootloader" to go Download screen. In there, there is no Knox Warranty info; it is only says like hold Power + Volume Down for more than 7 seconds to Cancel.

So where is that Knox Warranty status?

Comment: According to SamsungKnox.com : If the Knox bit has tripped:

- A new Workspace can no longer be created on such a device.
- The data encrypted and stored in an existing Workspace can no longer be retrieved.
- Other Samsung services that utilize Knox security stop working (Samsung Pay, Secure Folder.)

Comment: but Knox Warranty counter, where is it?

Comment: Finally found the answer on the web :

Volume Up and Down and simultaneously connect the device to PC using USB type-C.

https://www.hardreset.info/devices/samsung/samsung-galaxy-tab-s6/download-mode/

Comment: from terminal type cmd *'df -ah'* if you can see any knox related mounts, warranty is in valid state */data/knox/secure_fs*

Comment: Hi, looks like you've found the solution by yourself, which is great! Consider post it as a proper answer since [self-answering is not only allowed, but even encouraged!](//android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). Thanks!